# Tile matrix multiplication when M doesn't equal N?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix-multiplication

Every algorithm I've come across always uses a square matrix for tiling matrix multiplication. Is it possible to tile MMM when the two matrices are of completely different sizes?

This is the code I'm using at the moment and I would like to try and add tiling to improve my performance.

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(x, R, r, row) private(i, j, k, temp)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (k = 0; k < x->n; k++){
        for (i = row; i < row+2; i++){
            temp = x->v[i*x->n+k];
            for (j = 0; j < R->n; j++){         
                r[i*R->n+j] += temp*R->v[k*R->n+j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The variable x, R, and r are matrix structures with m, n, and v defined to hold the size and data. Matrix x is a rotation matrix, so it is an identity matrix with data in two rows. That's why I am limiting the multiplication to two rows only.

Matrix x therefore has a size of 2xn and R has a size of mxn. Note: It has been defined that x's n is always R's m so there is no size mismatch.

Is it possible to tile this type of mismatched matrix multiplication and still get a performance gain?